# print word document (.docx) from a java application running as windows service

Tags: java, printing

i have written a small java application which is called by an java application running as a windows service. 
My java application calls the print method in order to print the word document: 
`java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().print(new File(targetfile));`

It works if i call the java application but it does not work if it is executed by the windows service.

What happens is that i have multiple ms word processes running in the background each time the window service tries to execute my java application.

Do you know how i can print from a windows service ?

Thanks,

Asad

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess... you need to run the Windows Service as a user with appropriate permissions to print.

By default a service will run as `System` or `LocalUser`, which will not be able to print. That's why it works when you call it but not the service. Try and set the `Log On` account for the service to your personal account and see if it works.